# "Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'x' of undefined" in the THREE.js library file when I try to implement THREE.SubdivisionModifier()?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The error's appearing at line 1631 in the THREE.js library file itself. Here's the code I'm running:

```
var cube_geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(.1, .1, .1, 10, 10, 10);
var smooth = cube_geo.clone();
  smooth.mergeVertices;
var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(2);
  modifier.modify(smooth);
var cube_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x000000, specular: 0x222222} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(smooth, cube_mat);
  scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: So when you set  break point and walk through the code, what line breaks it?

Comment: smooth.mergeVertices; is not a function call, even though mergeVertices is a function

Comment: @Flux, I replaced smooth.mergeVertices with smooth.mergeVertices(); it didn't fix the issue, but thanks for catching the error.

Comment: @espascarello, when I step through the code, the first caught exception seems to be in jquery.js, line 1254; it reads: "DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector."